# Typesafe Play sbt-plugin version 2.8.7 missing from maven repo1

Tags: scala, maven, typesafe, sbt-plugin

My build started failing about an hour ago with this error:

```
 [error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.8.7
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.8.7/sbt-plugin-2.8.7.pom
```

Sure enough, the version is gone from maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/

Is this normal?

Comment: sbt plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.7")

Answer (score 2):

Ahh. This is a scheduled brownout to show what will be impacted on May 1st by the sunset of bitTray...

https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

@Typesafe, it looks like the sbt-plugin DL in maven repo1 is just a redirect to bitTray. I think this should get fixed before May 1st or many people will be upset...

```
[error]   download error: Caught java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.mwz/sbt-sonar/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml (Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.mwz/sbt-sonar/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.mwz/sbt-sonar/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/mph43t/sbt_build_failing_bintray_brownout_today_april_12/